# Check a username in a login form

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, forms, authentication

I want the program checks if a specific name is typed(for example 'admin').If it is typed correctly i want to proceed on another form.I have this code but it turns me an error:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{        
    if (textBox1.Text = 'admin')
    {

        this.Hide();

        // Show another form.
        Form3 f2 = new Form3();
        f2.ShowDialog(this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

please use this

```
if (textBox1.Text == "admin")
        {

            this.Hide();

            // Show another form.
            Form3 f2 = new Form3();
            f2.ShowDialog(this);
        }
```

Comment: you cannot compare String with = operator

Comment: @Cody, can use == or .Equal() function for compare strings

Answer (score 1):

I think you want

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

        if (textBox1.Text.Equals("admin"))
        {

            this.Hide();

            // Show another form.
            Form3 f2 = new Form3();
            f2.ShowDialog(this);


        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't do Windows Forms development, but it might be this line of code:

```
if (textBox1.Text = 'admin')
```

should be

```
if (textBox1.Text == 'admin')
```

Comment: You need to do `textBox1.Text.Equals("admin")` see my answer below